# How to get values from other rows based on multiple conditions in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df -

```
    +--------+--------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
    | GameID | TeamID | Team               | OpponentID | Opponent           | Location | score    |
    +--------+--------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
    | 1      | 1      | Alabama            | 2          | Jacksonville State | H        | 1.098633 |
    +--------+--------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
    | 1      | 2      | Jacksonville State | 1          | Alabama            | V        | 0.756562 |
    +--------+--------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
    | 2      | 3      | UAB                | 4          | Alcorn State       | H        | 1.270638 |
    +--------+--------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
    | 2      | 4      | Alcorn State       | 3          | UAB                | V        | 0.682791 |
    +--------+--------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
```

Each row represnts one of two teams results from a distinct GameID. My goal is to have a final df that looks like this

```
+--------+--------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+-----------------+
| GameID | TeamID | Team               | OpponentID | Opponent           | Location | score    | opponents score |
+--------+--------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+-----------------+
| 1      | 1      | Alabama            | 2          | Jacksonville State | H        | 1.098633 | 0.756562        |
+--------+--------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+-----------------+
| 1      | 2      | Jacksonville State | 1          | Alabama            | V        | 0.756562 | 1.098633        |
+--------+--------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+-----------------+
| 2      | 3      | UAB                | 4          | Alcorn State       | H        | 1.270638 | 0.682791        |
+--------+--------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+-----------------+
| 2      | 4      | Alcorn State       | 3          | UAB                | V        | 0.682791 | 1.270638        |
+--------+--------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+-----------------+
```

I am stuck on how to look up values that match criteria with different column names. Thanks!

Comment: `df.merge(df, left_on=['GameID','TeamID'], right_on=['GameID', 'OpponentID'], how'left')` and rename accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `merge()`  method:

```
resultdf=df.merge(df[['GameID','OpponentID','score']], left_on=['GameID','TeamID'], right_on=['GameID','OpponentID'], how='left')
```

Now make use of `drop()` method:

```
result.drop(columns=['OpponentID_y'])
```

Finally make use of `rename()` method:

```
result=result.rename(columns={'OpponentID_x':'OpponentID','score_x':'score','score_y':'opponents score'})
```

Now if you print `result` you will get your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Using [Pandas merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) solves your query very easily. You can achieve the desired result using the following code:

```
df_merge = df.merge(df, on=['GameID','TeamID'], how='outer', suffixes=(None, '_y'))
#print("Merged Dataset")
#display(df_merge)
df_merge.drop(['Team_y', 'OpponentID_y', 'Opponent_y', 'Location_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df_merge.rename( columns={'Score_y':'Opponent Score'}, inplace=True)
#print("Final Dataset")
#display(df_merge)
```

Oputput:
[image: Dataset before and after merge]